# Circulant embedding in python

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, math

I'm pretty new with Python. I've been trying to write a python script for Alg 12 in attached image, but keep getting the below error..could some one please assist?[Code Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHPHN.png) :

```
def circ(x,n):
    t = np.arange(0,n,1)
    g = np.exp(-10*t/n)*np.cos(-10*math.pi*t/n) #Given covariance function
    e = np.arange(n-1,0,-1)
    g_rev = np.array(np.exp(-10*e/n)*np.cos(-10*math.pi*e/n))
    s = np.hstack((0,g_rev))
    gamma = np.concatenate((g,s))
    zero = np.zeros((2*n-len(x)))
    x_x = np.hstack((x,zero))
    z = fft(np.conjugate(x_x))/2*n
    lamb = fft(np.conjugate(gamma))
    z_z = np.dot(lamb,z)
    zz = fft(np.conjugate(z_z))
    return z[:n+1]

## example##
n=6
x=np.array([1,1,1]) #initial guess vector
circ(x,n)
```

Will also appreciate feedback/tips on how to simplify my code?

[Alg 12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R67ft.png)

Comment: Your first step should be to define the fft function somewhere. Maybe you are using a library? Also, note that SO strongly prefers text as text, not as image.

Comment: Thanks. Yep using Scipy package for fft.. code seems to work now that I changed the z_z = np.dot(lamb,z) to z_z = lamb*z